# Should I create a new CacheItemPolicy for every item I add to a System.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCache?

Tags: c#, .net, caching

If by default I want to create a cache where everything expires at 5 am, would I need to create a new [CacheItemPolicy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.aspx) for each item that I cache, or would I could a create a default 5 am CacheItemPolicy and reuse it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `AbsoluteExpiration` then you have to create a new one for every item. if you are using `SlidingExpiration` then a sinple time span might be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you want every item expire individually, yes you have to create a policy for every item.

If you want to expire all items at once, you can create a Policy for each item with has a change monitor to another item in the cache. And the moment you remove that one other item, all items which monitor that item will be removed as well.